# jsch channel gets disconnected when called for the second time

Tags: java, jsch, channel

My requirement is to connect to remote machine via ssh using java . I am using jsch to do the same. I have a sequence of commands to be executed and each command execution depends on the output of the previous command.

Fox example, if I am executing:

```
 ls -l
```

after login into my remote machine by calling:

```
runCommand(“ls -l\n”);
```

Based on the output I get from the above step I need to create a directory:

```
runCommand(“mkdir test\n”);
```

On executing this I am getting:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request
at com.jcraft.jsch.Request.write(Request.java:65)
at com.jcraft.jsch.RequestPtyReq.request(RequestPtyReq.java:76)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSession.sendRequests(ChannelSession.java:212)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelShell.start(ChannelShell.java:44)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:152)
at com.apple.mailmove.ssh.ExecuteSecureShellCommand.runCommand(ExecuteSecureShellCommand.java:90)
at com.apple.mailmove.ssh.ExecuteSecureShellCommand.main(ExecuteSecureShellCommand.java:160)
```

and here is the `runCommad` code:

```
//Find below my method
 public void runCommand(String command)
  {
  try{
    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes());
   channel.setInputStream(is);
    channel.setOutputStream(baos);
    channel.connect(15 * 1000);
    // Wait three seconds for this demo to complete (ie: output to be streamed to us).
    Thread.sleep(3*1000);
    for (int timeout = 200000; timeout > 0; timeout--) 
    {
      if(baos.size() != 0)
      {
        System.out.println(baos.toString());
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("No output!!!!");
        Thread.sleep(5000); // wait a bit then try again
      }
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

Checked the connection status with

```
channel.isConnected
```

method before `channel.conenct(15*1000)` is called and it displayed `true`. Once `channel.conenct(15*1000)` is called the channel connection status returns false.

I am not able to understand why the channel gets disconnected when `channel.connect(15*1000)` is called for the second time. Is there any other way to execute the commands one by one so that I could get the output of previous command and execute the second command?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show how you create the channel object, and how you call `runCommand()` for each command that you want to run?

Answer (score 1):

For running one or more commands via SSH, I would recommend to use the exec channel that JSch provides. For a full example, see [this page](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html).

You'll have to change your code to create a new channel for each command that you want to run:

```
public void runCommand(String command) {
    ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
    channel.setCommand(command);

    try (InputStream stdOut = channel.getInputStream(); 
         InputStream stdErr = channel.getErrStream()) {
        channel.connect(TIMEOUT);
        // read from stdOut and stdErr
    }

    channel.disconnect();
}
```